# Changing paragraph formatting for dialogs

Tags: spacing, environments

In my document I set `\parindent` to `0pt` and `\parskip` to `\baselineskip`. However, this formatting is not appropriate for dialogs, so I have defined an environment to alter the spacing.

```
\newenvironment{Dialog}{%
    \par
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parindent}{1em}}{%
    \par
    \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    }
```

The problem is that after the dialog I still get vertical space, which I do not want to have.

[image]

How can I get rid of it?

Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{Dialog}{%
    \par
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parindent}{1em}}{%
    \par
    \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    }

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

    Some text here, now the dialog starts
    \begin{Dialog}
        --- Which phrase should I not google under any circumstances?

        --- ``Crazy LaTeX stuff''.
    \end{Dialog}    
    Now the text continues.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `\parskip`?

Comment: @egreg Isn't it the amount of space between paragraphs?

Comment: You could use `\mbox{}\\ ` instead of `\par` as a workaround. Or add a `\vskip-\parskip` after the `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}`.

Comment: The problem is that the `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` takes effect if the new paragraph doesn't start before it.

Comment: But are you sure this is the right way to set up your `Dialog`? What should happen if a line is longer than a line? Perhaps a custom `itemize` which uses `---` as the item label would be better.

Comment: @Skillmon in Russian literature a direct speech stars as a new paragraph: no vertical space and an indentation. I just find it better if the dash in the beginning of the line is indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `\vskip\dialogunskip` (with `\dialogunskip=-\parskip`) to eliminate the space. It also shows the problem of very long dialog lines: What happens if the line of text is longer than one line and ends at the margin of a following line? Then you can't tell where speech ends and where the rest of the text begins.

Also I created a second environment with cleaner syntax (imho). It suffers from the same problem, though (as it produces identical output).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\newdimen\dialogunskip
\newenvironment{Dialog}
  {%
    \dialogunskip=-\parskip
    \setlength\parskip{0pt}%
    \setlength\parindent{1em}%
    \par
  }
  {%
    \par
    \vskip\dialogunskip
  }

\newenvironment{dialog}
  {%
    \dialogunskip=-\parskip
    \newcommand*\say[1][]% optional argument to keep track of who says what
      {%
        \par---
        \ignorespaces
      }%
    \parskip=0pt
    \parindent=1em
  }
  {%
    \par
    \vskip\dialogunskip
  }

\parindent=0pt\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}
\blindduck
\begin{Dialog}
  --- Which phrase should I not google under any circumstances?

  --- ``Crazy LaTeX stuff''.
\end{Dialog}
\blindduck
\begin{dialog}
  \say[Underduckling] Yes, I'll do as you say.
  \say[Duck] Good, but hurry.
  \say Who says this?
  \say[Very long text] And I like to speak a lot which is why this line of
  text is pretty long. In fact it is so long that it does need more than one
  line. Random word: guiaendu
\end{dialog}
\blindduck
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I mean that you need simply to add `\vskip\baselineskip` in the beginning part of your environment. The `\parskip` is inserted in the time when new paragraph is started. This is the reason why the first dialogue paragraph has not visible `\parskip` space before.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{Dialog}{%
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \parskip=0pt
    \parindent=1em
    }{%
    \par
    \parskip=\baselineskip
    \parindent=0pt
    }

\parskip=\baselineskip
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

    Some text here, now the dialog starts
    \begin{Dialog}
        --- Which phrase should I not google under any circumstances?

        --- ``Crazy LaTeX stuff''.
    \end{Dialog}    
    Now the text continues.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler to make `Dialogue` an `itemize-like` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Dialog}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[Dialog]{label = \textemdash, nosep}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

    Some text here, now the dialog starts
    \begin{Dialog}
       \item Which phrase should I not google under any circumstances?

        \item ``Crazy LaTeX stuff''.
    \end{Dialog}
    Now the text continues.

Another paragraph with some more text

\end{document}
```

[image]